# Python issues output. String manipulation

Tags: python, string

I got the following code, however at the time of the output (txt file) it will not return a value just a `None` however that happensw when I save it to a txt file, when I simply run the program it does display the values that I want.

```
archi2=open('googletabla.txt', 'w')

nicCoor=open("C:\Users\SistBa\PycharmProjects\seguropais\SeguroPais\NIC.txt", "r")
coorNiclines=nicCoor.readlines()

poly = []

for NicaLines0 in coorNiclines: #leyendo las coordenadas de Nicaragua
    if(len(NicaLines0))>5:
        NicLines=re.sub(r'99.000', '',str(NicaLines0))
        NicLines1=re.sub(r' 0.000', '',str(NicLines))
        if NicLines1.isspace()==False :
            line = ','.join(NicLines1.split())
            lista=str(poly.extend(zip(*[iter(map(float, line.split(',')))]*2)))

            archi2.write(lista+'\n')
print poly
archi2.close()
```

My output on python is:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/SistBa/PycharmProjects/seguropais/SeguroPais/game
[(14.993, -83.152), (14.959, -83.172), (14.952, -83.2), (14.891, -83.262), (14.762, -83.31), (14.633, -83.283), (14.456, -83.221), (14.333, -83.2), (14.265, -83.214), (14.122, -83.297)...]
```

Process finished with exit code 0

however on my txt file is the following:

```
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None...
```

Comment: please add some contents of `C:\Users\SistBa\PycharmProjects\seguropais\SeguroPais\NIC.txt`

Comment: use a print statement after "lista=..." for debugging purpose to see if anything is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are string-converting the result of the list-method "extend", and write this. But it returns None, so that's why you end up with a bunch of None in your output.

Also, you probably don't even want the extend, because you write in each iteration, so for all NicaLines0 you will write it and all the preceding lines.

Then you completely unnecessarily split the NicLines1 only to join it again and then split it. Just write

```
line = NicLines1.split()
```

and remove the line.split(",") on the following line.

You will at some point getting into troubles using backslashes in filenames if you don't either properly escape them, or use raw-strings.

And I don't know what your desired output is, so I can't suggest a replacement for the lista-assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Visual addition to answer above.

The problem here is that extend actually always returns None

```
>>> a.extend('a')
>>> a
['a']
```

So change it to something like this:

```
archi2=open('googletabla.txt', 'w')

nicCoor=open("C:\Users\SistBa\PycharmProjects\seguropais\SeguroPais\NIC.txt", "r")
coorNiclines=nicCoor.readlines()

poly = []

for NicaLines0 in coorNiclines: #leyendo las coordenadas de Nicaragua
    if(len(NicaLines0))>5:
        NicLines=re.sub(r'99.000', '',str(NicaLines0))
        NicLines1=re.sub(r' 0.000', '',str(NicLines))
        if NicLines1.isspace()==False :
            line = ','.join(NicLines1.split())
            new_val = zip(*[iter(map(float, line.split(',')))]*2)
            poly.extend(new_val)
            lista=str(new_val)

            archi2.write(lista+'\n')
print poly
archi2.close()
```